# Scene KIT Deep of 3D View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, 3d, scenekit

I'm new to 3D programming in Scene Kit.

I'm trying to understand Why when I move the camera to my object - it is distorted and not displayed. It seems that the depth settings of the scene are not adjusted...

[image]

Maybe there are some restrictions on the depth of the scene about which I do not even guess?

Why can not I view all the details of my 3D object in the "DAE" format near me?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Demo app in git hub:

https://github.com/Mor940k/SCENEKIT

Comment: You might need to set the `zNear` of your camera.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!